# Opengl matrix without glm

Tags: matrix, opengl

Does anybody know what the order of a 4x4 GLfloat array matrix for transforming a 2D rectangle is? I don't want to use glm or cglm to make my life easy. I'm trying to use the least amount of libraries as possible.
Is the order something like this:

`{ px, sx, rx, 0, py, sy, ry, 0, pz, sz, rz, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }` ?

If not what is it?

Thanks!

Comment: What are px,, sx,, rx, ...? OpenGL doesn't care whether your matrices are row major or column major, as long as you set the correct parameters in `glUniformMatrix4fv`.

Comment: px - position x ; sx - size x ; rx - rotation x

Comment: Ok. That's not at all how transformation matrices work. A transformation matrix containing rotation, translation and scale is the result of a multiplication of at least three matrices, one for each of the primitive operations. If your rotations are rotations around the global axis (aka: Euler Angles), then you need a separate rotation matrix for each of them and you have to decide on the order. You really need to read up on the math: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

4x4 matrix is for 3D.

```
Xx  Yx  Zx  Tx
Xy  Yy  Zy  Ty
Xz  Yz  Zz  Tz
0   0   0   1

(Xx, Xy, Xz) - left (or right) vector
(Yx, Yy, Yz) - up vector
(Zx, Zy, Zz) - forward vector
(Tx, Ty, Tz) - translation (position) vector

indices:
m00 m01 m02 m03
m10 m11 m12 m13
m20 m21 m22 m23
m30 m31 m32 m33

Order: m00, m10, m20, m30, m01, m11, m21, m31, m02, m12, m22, m32, m03, m13, m23, m33
```

If you need only 2D transformations you can use a 3x3 matrix.

```
Xx  Yx  Tx
Xy  Yy  Ty
0   0   1

Order: m00, m10, m20, m01, m11, m21, m02, m12, m22
```

Or you want this?

```
Xx  Yx  0  Tx
Xy  Yy  0  Ty
0   0   1  0
0   0   0  1
```

Comment: You forgot about scaling. And OpenGL can handle both, column major or row major data.

Comment: @BDL where I forgot about scaling?

Comment: @BDL technically yes, you can use row major. But the most common way is to use column major. Specifications such as gltf 2.0 uses column major, for example.